# how to use ng-repeat in js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I write this code but its not working

```
function tooltipHtml(n, d) {
    return "<b>" + n + "</b><table>" +
        "<hr style='margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;'/>" +
        "<tr ng-repeat=\"Tooltip in d.Tooltip\">" +
        "<td style='min-width:200px;'><div data-ng-bind=\"Tooltip.Name\"></div> = <div data-ng-bind=\"Tooltip.Value\"></div></td>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "</table>";
}
```

where

```
d.Tooltip =
    [{
            Name: "MGRert APropertsdfy Management",
            Value: 162
        },
        {
            Name: "MGRss SManagement",
            Value: 1621
        },
        {
            Name: "Novssa CASFS",
            Value: 1612
        }
    ]
```

is this possible to create html in js file.

Comment: You can achieve this by creating a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Please read this article, how to use $compile for string type javascript code
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: Please, don't write HTML like this when using AngularJS...

Comment: You can try `tooltip-template`, should be a cleaner way